# How can I change the rootViewController to a VC that has not been loaded yet?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Imagine an application like Twitter in which once you log in, you never see the sign in screen again until you log out. I have done this by changing the initial viewController in the appDelegate on launch. However, when going to sign out, there is now nothing below the new VC in the stack to dismiss to. How can I properly make the sign in screen the rootViewController after the initial view has loaded so that I can dismiss on logout?

In appDelegate I have changed the initialVC like so:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

And then I would like to basically insert the signInVC beneath my initial VC so that I can "dismiss" to it.

Comment: I'm not firm on what Twitter's log in screen looks like, but could it just be a view instead of a ViewController?

Comment: I'm not trying to emulate Twitter exactly, but thats just how they do it. Basically I want the sign in VC at the bottom of the stack, but only after launch.

Comment: @Cody Lucas When you sign in you are changing root view controller to some other controller in other words that's is the entry point now. I would say at logout change the entry point back to login controller.And to identify login state you can save bool value in user defaults.

Comment: @TusharSharma currently I am trying to change the root vc when I log out, but instead of dismissing to it, it puts that vc on the top of the stack.

Comment: @Cody Lucas are you doing it with same code as above ? With identifier and controller be as login this time.ex-: let loginlViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginIdentifier") as loginController and update root as -: window.rootViewController = loginlViewController. But to get access to root window from logout screen you need to  get app delegate reference.

Answer (score 0):

Take a bool value called signup_status and store it in UserDefaults.standard and set it as false

And change this value to true when user is logged in  and  and make is false when he is log out

Now in AppDelegate check for user is login or not

```
  if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signup_status"){

  //if true the dont show login page and make home screen root view controller


      let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homepage") as! homepageViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController 




  }else {


 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! login
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController 



 }
```

now in logout

set the value of UserDefaults.standard for key signup_status false

```
     UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "signup_status")
     let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! login
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
```